# How to set data on ActivatedRoute for spectator test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator

Does anybody know how to test the resolved route data in the component using Spectator? In my component code I get the Todo array data and set it to dataSource for the material-table. I want to test that if I stub ActivatedRoute with a Todo(), it will populate my dataSource.

I cannot get this test to work. I have tried multiple ways of setting route.data. 
None of the examples online specifically show how to test the route this way.

Any ideas?

```
let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ListTodoComponent>;

  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    declarations:[
      DateTimeFormatPipe,
      LoaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterTestingModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      FlexLayoutModule,
      MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatPaginatorModule],
    component: ListTodoComponent
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
    spectator.activatedRouteStub.setAllData([new Todo(133,'some 
   title','dsdsd','dsdsds','dsds','dsdss')]);
  });

  it('should populate dataSource with one todo', () => {
    spectator.component.ngOnInit();
    expect(spectator.component.dataSource.data.length).toBe(1);
    expect(spectator.component.dataSource.data[0]).toHaveClass('Todo');
  });
```

Component code

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.pipe(
      take(1),
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res['data']);
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the data you can do it in the initial `createRoutingFactory` params:

```
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
    declarations:[
      DateTimeFormatPipe,
      LoaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterTestingModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      FlexLayoutModule,
      MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatPaginatorModule],
    component: ListTodoComponent
  });
```

In your example you're using `setAllData` which is something I would only use inside an individual test once the TestBed is bootstrapped.